# Add or update pandas dataframe from list of value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
>>> df
  name  count
0    a      1
1    b      2
2    c      0
```

I want to update the value using this list

```
 l = ['a','b','d']
```

So my updated df should look like this

```
>>> df
  name  count
0    a      2
1    b      3
2    c      0
3    d      1
```

Only way I can think of is using loop. Can you people suggest any other way.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create `Series` from list and get counts by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then create `Series` from `df` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) together, last for `DataFrame` use [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html)
 and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
l = ['a','b','d']

add = pd.Series(l).value_counts()
print (add)
d    1
a    1
b    1
dtype: int64

df1 = (df.set_index('name')['count']
         .add(add, fill_value=0)
         .astype(int)
         .rename_axis('name')
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  name  count
0    a      2
1    b      3
2    c      0
3    d      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to add the values on top of each other and `GroupBy.count`:

```
x = sorted(list(set(df['name'].tolist() + l)))
new = pd.concat([df['name'].repeat(df['count']).to_frame()
                 , pd.DataFrame({'name':l})]).groupby('name')['name'].count()
new = new.reindex(x, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='count')
```

**Output**

```
print(new)
  name  count
0    a      2
1    b      3
2    c      0
3    d      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a Counter would be appropriate in these situations.
The only downside is conversion from df to dict and vice versa.

```
from collections import Counter

# initialize your variables
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'count': [1, 2, 0]})
l = ['a', 'b', 'd']

# convert to dict with name - count pairs and update with counter of l
df_as_dict = dict(zip(df['name'].values, df['count'].values))
df_as_dict.update(Counter(df_as_dict) + Counter(l))

# create dataframe with updates values
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': list(df_as_dict.keys()), 
                       'count': list(df_as_dict.values())})
# ensure df format
new_df = new_df.sort_values('name').reset_index(drop=True)

new_df
```

### Output

```
   count name
0      2    a
1      3    b
2      0    c
3      1    d
```